# HomeAsUp indicator in Toolbar not working

Tags: android, toolbar

I want to change HomeAsUp indicator in Toolbar and replace default arrow.
How can i do this?
Below is my code, but I can't change icon.
Please help.

Styles :

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_back_white</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_back_white</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar in layout :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Toolabr in Activity :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back_white);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Activity in Menifest :

```
<activity
        android:name=".GroupInfoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back_white);
```

to

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back_white));
```